# nodejs multer rejecting to display image file path

Tags: node.js, fs, multer

I get this error when I try to return the details of an image in json format

```
(node:11628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

this is my model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const uploadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  brandimage: {
    filename: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    contentType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    imageBase64: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  brandname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
});
UploadeModel = mongoose.model("graphicsUpload", uploadSchema);

module.exports = UploadeModel;
```

multer storage config

```
const uploads = multer({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "../uploads");
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var ext = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));
    cb(null, file.originalname + Date.now() + "-" + ext);
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      return cb(new Error("Please upload a valid image"));
    }
    cb(undefined, true);
  },
});
```

and the route

```
router.post(
  "/addbrands",
  uploads.array("brandimage", 2),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const buffer = req.files;
    if (!buffer) {
      const error = new Error("Please choose files");
      error.httpStatusCode = 400;
      return next(error);
    }

    const imgArray = buffer.map((file) => {
      let img = fs.readFileSync(file.path
);
      return (encoded_image = img.toString("base64"));

    res.json(imgArray);
  }
);
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error and can't find an answer online, please help and also if you can tell me how to make req and save with an object in an object as shown in the mongoose format above

thanks

Comment: How is `uploads` configured?

Comment: @eol please check the code again, I just added the multer storage which is saved in the uploads variable

Comment: Looks ok - where/which module is `sharp` coming from?

Comment: @eol its been commented out. Its a mistake that its there in the code